# the selected disc is of gpt partition style error

Tags: windows-8, uefi, gpt

I want to install windows 8, but I am getting this error **the selected disc is of gpt partition style**. I already have Ubuntu 14.04 install with UEFI boot.

I have 3 partition in the order of:

1. UEFI boot partition
2. Ubuntu
3. free space

what to do next?

Comment: windows only installs to gpt partitioned drives with UEFI. Or if drive is MBR it only installs in BIOS. And if you force install in BIOS mode it converts to MBR, erasing drive. YOu need to boot Windows in UEFI mode to install in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a note: This is a Windows 8.* error, not an Ubuntu one, so it's better suited to a Windows forum.

The question has been asked and answered [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/windows-cannot-be-installed-on-this-disk-the/1637c1c8-2f7c-47f1-956d-88b639388ac2), so see if the answers on that forum resolve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 does support GPT. What you need is to format your USB installation drive to GPT. Use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Comment: I tried rufus but for windows 7 and it didnt worked because at the time of installation it was asking me for drivers

Comment: You blow my mind here. The question was about Windows 8. With Rufus you can solve your problem about [gpt partition style](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn336946.aspx). If you have problem with drivers during installation perhaps this help. [How to Load SATA Drivers](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9573-sata-driver-load-windows-8-setup.html) Do no use UEFI Legacy mode, it is known to couse some problems.